# Exponential Averaging using Eigen

Tags: eigen, eigen3

Consider the following code.

```
const int N = 100;
const float alpha = 0.9;

Eigen::MatrixXf myVec = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(N,1);
Eigen::MatrixXf symmetricMatrix(N, N);
for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
        symmetricMatrix(i,j) = symmetricMatrix(j,i) =   i+j;

symmetricMatrix *= alpha;
symmetricMatrix += ((1-alpha)*myVec*myVec.adjoint());
```

It essentially implements the exponential averaging.
I know that the last line may be optimized in the following way.

```
symmetricMatrix_copy.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().rankUpdate(myVec, 1-alpha);
```

I would like to know whether I can combine the last two lines in an efficient way.
In short, I would like to compute  `A = alpha*A+(1-alpha)*(x*x')`.

Comment: With "efficiently", are you referring to the syntax or performance, or both?

Comment: Both...but the main concern is performance in terms of computation time.

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, you should declare `myVec` as `Eigen::VectorXf`, if it is guaranteed to be a vector. And make sure you compile with `-O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG`.

You can try these alternatives (I'm using `A` and `v` to save typing), which one is the fastest likely depends on your problem-size and your CPU:

```
A.noalias() = alpha * A + (1.0f-alpha)*v*v.adjoint();
A.noalias() = alpha * A + (1.0f-alpha)*v.lazyProduct(v.adjoint());
A.noalias() = alpha * A + ((1.0f-alpha)*v).lazyProduct(v.adjoint());
A.noalias() = alpha * A + v.lazyProduct((1.0f-alpha)*v.adjoint());

A.triangularView<Eigen::Upper>() = alpha * A + (1.0f-alpha)*v*v.adjoint();
// or any `lazyProduct` as above.
```

Unfortunately, `.noalias()` and `.triangularView()` can't be combined at the moment.

You can also consider computing this:

```
A.selfadjointView<Eigen::Upper>().rankUpdate(v, (1.0f-alpha)/alpha);
```

and every `N` iterations scale your `A` matrix by `pow(alpha, N)`

Comment: Eigen Documentation does not recommend the use of lazyProduct. "This version of the matrix product can be much much slower. So use it only if you know what you are doing and that you measured a true speed improvement."

Comment: @Soo Yes, you need to benchmark what is the fastest in your case.